# Azure Service Bus Camel component receive control

Tags: apache-camel, azureservicebus, spring-camel

We are attempting to migrate from the Camel AMQP component to the Camel Azure Service Bus component for our services that receive messages. With the AMQP component we can specify maxConcurrentConsumers as a means of controlling how many messages a service instance can process at the same time. With the ASB component, no such config parameter exists. What mechanism can we employ to control the number of messages being processed at once? Or concern is: what happens if the component has consumed and is processing 50 messages and the pod crashes? The documentation states that messages are not acknowledged until the exchange ends successfully but I am skeptical.

We are very early in our learnings and to this point we have only created a service that subscribes to a queue and processes messages.

Answer (score 0):

I dont expert in asb but I used it in previous company there are two receive mode in asb Receive and delete and Peek in this case u should work with peek mode. camel has peekNumMaxMessages parameter and more details about receive mode in asb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how did that work? Peek messages, then receive each by id and complete it?

Comment: for example I received 50 messages in once , first and second messages completed and third get exception , 48 messages will not process asb will put 48 messages to queeue after a time your client will consume 50 messages . its is basic period of messaging you can do some demo for see it